# CSS Perspective doesn't work on body

Tags: css

It works if I have div wrapper:

```
.body {
  perspective: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRzXJe

But doesn't if I apply it to the body tag:

```
body {
  perspective: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VXjqXM

Comment: @Pete to be able to use libs that hook up to the window scroll event.

Comment: @TemaniAfif could you please help me understand the issue? what is different with the scroll?

Answer (score 3):

Don't have a good understanding of this behaviour but the fix is to add

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```